# How to trigger XML (XSLT) transformation by using C# code ? How to pass parameters ("param"s) to XSLT?

Tags: c#, xslt

**This is the question I posted :**

Hi, I have an XSLT code which needs to take parameters (say one or two) from C# code .. (If you want to know, why I need to do this, then let me explain, I have to parse an input XML from certain external application, however I need to edit data of some tags taking the values of some other application which could be defined in complex C# code, I don't have to worry about it) .. for the time being and for demo purpose, I need to declare some strings and pass them to XSLT following the action of triggering the transformation.

I tried to search google, but didn't work. If you get to know ANYTHING regarding this, please send me corresponding link or information ..

As I am not familiar with C# (thats the reason stuck with problem) simpler coding would help a lot ..

And also please specify which "project type" should I select ..

thanks in advance ..

**And the solution is here:**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltargumentlist.addparam.aspx
simple and works very conveniently ..

thanQ [MandoMando](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190708/mandomando) and thanQ "stackoverflow"

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778299/1778326#1778326 - just add an `XsltArgumentList` with the param values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, it's not necessary to create DOM objects like `XmlDocument` or `XDocument` to execute transforms.

```
XslCompiledTransfrom xslt = new XsltCompiledTransform()
xslt.Load(transformPath);
XsltArgumentList args = new XsltArgumentList();
args.AddParam("name", "myNamespace", value)
using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(inputPath))
using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(outputPath))
{
   xslt.Transform(xr, args, xw);
}
```

Note that the `Create()` methods of `XmlReader` and `XmlWriter` have a formidable number of overloads.  I use `XmlWriter.Create(Console.Out)` a lot when I'm prototyping.

Comment: In some cases (i.e. html output), a StringWriter is better for the output (as it won't be strict xml), but a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have your looked at [this](http://projects.ischool.washington.edu/tabrooks/545/2004Autumn/ContentManagement/PassingParameters.htm) article?  It talks about passing params to xslt in C#.  I believe it is possible to do.

Comment: ya .. exactly that is where I got the Idea .. but I am looking for some thing ready or kind of "detailed" tutorial ..
(Please don't mind .. its a human psychology to go for more lazy things) .. If I don't get any more suggestions I will rollback to the same site to start from scratch.. your advice is valuable .. thnx for the reply ..

Comment: This page also has an example that's easy to follow: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltargumentlist.addparam.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty:

```
XmlDocument x = new XmlDocument();
x.Load("yourxmldoc.xml");
XslTransform t = new XslTransform();
XsltArgumentList xslArg = new XsltArgumentList();
xslArg.AddParam("parameterName", "", parameterValue);
StringWriter swEndDoc = new System.IO.StringWriter();
t.Load("yourdoc.xslt");
t.Transform(x, xslArg, swEndDoc, null);
String output = swEndDoc.ToString();
```

Comment: I was about to upvote, but this code is now out of date... it will work, but its not the right classes any more.

Comment: We don't need XDocument anymore here .. Code works fine without that .. passing the parameter list is "typical" I agree with that ..

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly straightforward - note that I'm using XDocument and XslCompiledTransform:

```
XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(fromSource); // Or whatever means to get XML
XsltArgumentList xslArgs = new XsltArgumentList();

// For as many params as you need
xslArgs.AddParam("paramName", "", "paramValue");

// Create and load an XSLT transform - with params matching param names above
XslCompiledTransform t = new XslCompiledTransform();
t.Load(XSLTPath);

StringWriter outputDoc = new System.IO.StringWriter();
t.Transform(xmlDocument.CreateReader(), xslArgs, outputDoc);

String output = outputDoc.ToString();
```

Comment: We don't need XDocument anymore here .. Code works fine without that .. passing the parameter list is "typical" I agree with that ..

Comment: You're right, I just chopped the code from something that's live and working (-: