# PDF Generation using C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, xml, pdf

I am trying to create a PDF generator using C#.NET but having some major difficulties. I have an xml files with the data and an xslt file for the template of the pdf. I tried many different libraries out there but can't seem to get this working properly. Can anyone suggest an example I can use that shows how to do this. 
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What does your xslt transform output?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using the excellent TransformXMLToHTML method by [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778299/simplest-way-to-transform-xml-to-html-with-xslt-in-c) to transform XML + XSLT to HTML.

The HTML can then be transformed to PDF.

This approach may have been slower than editing a PDF as binary.   But it was stable and gave me full control over content quality.

**Step 1 - transform XML + XSLT to HTML**

I needed to add Nugets including:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Xml.ReaderWriter/

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Xls;
using System.IO;

public static string TransformXMLToHTML(string inputXml, string xsltString)
{
    XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
    using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsltString))) {
        transform.Load(reader);
    }
    StringWriter results = new StringWriter();
    using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(inputXml))) {
        transform.Transform(reader, null, results);
    }
    return results.ToString();
}
```

**Step 2 - Transform HTML to PDF**

I tried:

- https://github.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf
- IronPdf which was non free to deploy but the free trial was quite successful (https://ironpdf.com/examples/using-html-to-create-a-pdf/)
- https://github.com/ArthurHub/HTML-Renderer

All worked and had their weaknesses and strengths.

[Lets not get into a debate about the best C# HTML to PDF converter.]

Comment: 2021 update. We are using IronPDF and the above solution in production and it is working.